# ionic cordova [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess

Tags: android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the command **ionic cordova build** and I get the following errors and I don't find a clear answer on this. With this error I can not pass the application to android studio

cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 14 source files in 635ms
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\andres\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\andres\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\andres\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Program Files\gradle-7.5\bin\gradle.BAT -p C:\Users\andres\Desktop\aplicacion\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Users\andres\Desktop\aplicacion\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
  **[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.**

  ```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrzMt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with you java version according to the question description.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4\bin\java.exe

Java 11 is supported for [cordova 10+](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk) which allows for the same minimum Android versions as cordova 9. This should now be the preferred solution.

So you need to check your ionic, cordova and java version and set it accordingly.

I hope this helps.